# Can you name an abstract class Object?

Tags: java

Considering everything is object oriented etc, so names have to describe the object and what it is, I have an abstract class that sub classes inherit from. These are all objects on the screen (it's a game), i.e, player, and a weight (trapezoid weight). I have it currently named Character but it doesn't seem fitting as the weight is not a Character itself, it only inherits properties from Character.

Could I call this class "Object" without it breaking conventions? - could someone come up with a more appropriate name?

Comment: That's a very bad idea.  Java already has an `Object` class.

Comment: @Ajai: Wrong; `Object` is not a keyword.  http://ideone.com/4Nhwr1

Comment: I would name it `Entity`.

Comment: There are many alternative names - how about `Thing` or `Blob`. Perhaps you could make use of what it does - how about `HasShapeAndWeight`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Technically, you could - but it's a very, very bad idea, so don't.**

Longer explanation: The `Object` class already in Java is `java.lang.Object` - so there's no *technical* reason why you could create another `Object` class in another package, just as you *could* create another `String` class in another package. (Actually, technically speaking you could even create your own `java.lang.Object`, but I'm not even going to go there!)

However:

> Could I call this class "Object" without it breaking conventions?

Without breaking *convention*? Not in the slightest. You should never duplicate such commonly used class names elsewhere, especially those in java.lang. It would be considered incredibly bad code design.

In terms of a better name, `Actor` or `Sprite` may be two good alternatives.

Comment: @Vash Because it seems like a good 1 word description on what these objects do, and (more importantly) it doesn't have the potential to name clash with a core `java.lang` class.

Comment: I knew it was a terrible idea, but my mind went blank on all form of things. Actor seems most appropriate from my opinion although Sprite is equally valid. Although someone else mentioned Entity which I also like. Thanks! Marked as best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Java's `Object` class is part of the `java.lang` package which is automatically imported for every class file. If you name your class `Object` and forget to explicitly `import` it in other classes, you will have issues, thinking you're using `com.custom.Object` (your class), but actually using `java.lang.Object`, the JDK's.

Use a more descriptive name, `ApplicationObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The class beside the name has the path that is package.

```
 package org.stackoverflow

 public class Object {

 }
```

By default `java.lang` is prohibited package name so you can not do declare

```
package java.lang

public class Object {

}
```

The class names does not have to be unique in scope of whole world. Using the class path you are able to override the JVM definition of class.

Comment: Even creating `org.stackoverflow.Object` would, in my book, be an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: @Vash `java.lang` is a restricted package. You won't be allowed to compile such a `.java` file, afaik.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Thanks for that hint. You have right the compilation fail with a SecuriryException